# Accessing a wordpress blog from an Android application

Tags: android, mysql, wordpress, browser, webview

I want to display my Wordpress blog in an Android application.

I have tried a few things, but the browser kept opening to display the page.

I learned about the WebView class from the Android API but saw on the website that it can only handle static pages.

Is it possible to view a complete Wordpress website in an Android application? If so, how do you do this?

Appreciate the help in advance!

Thanks,

Comment: Please post your code. You were making some mistake.
You can display the all contents in the webview like the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.awwwards.com/websites/wordpress/");
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

give the internet permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: setWebViewClient(); method is important.
Otherwise all pages will be handled by systems / other browsers.